# Why are users downloading old versions of our iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Apple released for sale a critical update to our iOS app 7 days ago today. Since then, the vast majority of our App Store installs and updates have been the new version, but a small portion of the updates (less than 1%) are the old version, as reported by iTunes Connect. This has continued day after day, and is concerning because some users are getting a crash-prone version of our app.

How are users still updating to the old version 7 days after we released an update? Is there any way to prevent this?

(The targeted iOS versions have not changed; the app is and has only ever been available on the US store.)

Comment: Does your update target a higher iOS version?

Comment: No, we have not changed the targeted iOS versions between releases.

Comment: It could be Apple's servers haven't propagated. It could be other countries downloading your app because you didn't update your country list after they added new ones. It could be that those downloads are not legitimate and are from jailbroken phones or something like that.

Comment: We considered that, but our app is and has only ever been available on the US store. Furthermore, we know our user base quite well and don't suspect many of them have jailbroken.

Comment: App Store questions are, at the most of times, a playing in the dark thing. I believe you would be better requesting a support for your developer account and clarify this question. I don't believe apps that are installed outside the app store to be shown on iTunes connect...

Comment: OK, thank you for that suggestion. We had hoped that someone else might know the answer to save ourselves a support request.

Comment: I had a related issue that was caused by a change in team members. An older version had a slightly different staff than a newer version. (email address change). That was enough to cause some havoc. If you can fix it this way, great, otherwise, I agree with NSPunk - contact Apple Dev Support. They are pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this behavior before but not lasting more than 24 hours. Your app is released and the App Store app shows the update but still downloads the old IPA. My understanding is that some CDN (Akamai if you sniff the traffic) node has an old version and it never got purged. This is probably the reason that they mention in the "released to App Store email" that it can take 24 hours before it is available anywhere.

I think the best remedy is to email App Store support. Or submit a new version that changes something really minor in the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have seen this behavior on every update we release, typically lasting 5-7 days after release. Since no one else seems to have been in this situation, we will contact Apple.